# How to debug JAXB unmarshalling?

Tags: debugging, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm running into a problem with JAXB unmarshalling.  I think I have it properly coded, but my unmarshalled object returns with null parameters.  Consequently, I am assuming that when unmarshalling, JAXB is not seeing the appropriate XML structure that it is expecting.  However, I do not get any error messages or any exceptions thrown.

Is there anyway to step through the unmarshalling process to see exactly where/why it is failing to populate my object(s)?

The actual unmarshalling code is fairly mundane:

```
public <T> T unmarshall(Node node, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
    // Creating an unmarshaller
    Unmarshaller u = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz).createUnmarshaller();

    // unmarshal an instance node into  Java content
    return clazz.cast(u.unmarshal(node, clazz).getValue());
}
```

However, when I call it, I get an object of type clazz returned (as expected), but unpopulated.

The DOM object that I am trying to unmarshal is generated by a third party API.  I have already run into some extremely odd behaviours with the unmarshalling, which is why I would like to be able to debug the process.  For instance, if I try to unmarshal a sub-element within the DOM object (ie: doc.getByElementName("myElement").item(0)), it fails silently.  However, if I convert the document to a string, and reimport it into a new document, then it converts it fine.

I am starting to get quite frustrated not knowing how to debug this issue.

Thanks for any insights!

Eric

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One approach you could take is to use JAXB to generate an XML schema from your annotated classes.  This represents what JAXB expects the input document to look like.  Then validate your XML document against this XML schema to see if it conforms to JAXB's expectations.

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Never tried that before; will give it a shot.  But given that I generated the JAXB classes from an XSD, it seems like going backwards.  But I still don't find it to be an elegant solution.  JAXB is acting like a complete black box, and without any indicators explaining what it is doing, I have no idea what-so-ever why it is failing.  I would love to find a method to allow me to "see" what it is doing and/or where the problems lie.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried using the validator, and it is throwing an error that I don't understand.  I have created a seperate thread for that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761930/jaxb-unmarshal-validation-throws-cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-eleme).  If you can suggest anything, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, that is the best approach I have found so far because [other approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10227684/1864054) simply don't yield good and/or productive results. However, I would recommend against using `soapUI` for generating test messages since it generates a message skeleton without any (fake) data values, forcing you to manually type everything which is error prone, especially for large messages. Instead, Altova's XMLSpy works wonders. All you need to do is select the `create New SOAP request" item from the `SOAP` menu and, voila!, you got a perfectly working (fake) message.

Answer (score 21):

You can try using the default handler.

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(jaxbObjectClass);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());
```

From the javadocs:

> public class DefaultValidationEventHandler
>
> extends Object
>
> implements ValidationEventHandler
>
> JAXB 1.0 only default validation event handler. This is the default handler for all objects created from a JAXBContext that is managing schema-derived code generated by a JAXB 1.0 binding compiler. This handler causes the unmarshal and validate operations to fail on the first error or fatal error.

This will produce more verbose, useful output for debugging.

Comment: A comment or two about how this code snippet answers the question would be helpful.    DefaultValidationEventHandler is the old JAXB 1.0 handler - right?   Are you suggesting this as an answer because the old handler would spit out more verbose error messages?

Comment: From the javadocs:  

public class DefaultValidationEventHandler
extends Object
implements ValidationEventHandler

JAXB 1.0 only default validation event handler. This is the default handler for all objects created from a JAXBContext that is managing schema-derived code generated by a JAXB 1.0 binding compiler.

This handler causes the unmarshal and validate operations to fail on the first error or fatal error.

Answer (score 2):

Should anyone else stumble on this like I did. https://www.kevinhooke.com/2014/03/25/debugging-jaxb-unmarshalling-issues/

This blog post was essential

Pass the following into your start command

```
-Djaxb.debug=true
```

Then add the following EventHandler.

```
Unmarshaller um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
um.setEventHandler(new javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler());
```

hope that helps. In my jetty web app, this enables clear errors to bubble up and I found the namespace issue quite easily.