# JAXB unmarshal validation throws cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element error

Tags: validation, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm kind of new to JAXB and validation, and have spent several hours trying to figure out this problem to no avail. I've created a simple JAXB unmarshaller sample to parse an XML file. I have created an appropriate XSD file as well, but the validator keeps complaining that it is unable to find the declaration of an element.

I think it may be related to namespace issues, but I've tried everything I can think of and still can't seem to resolve the error. As far as I can tell, my XSD and XML are proper, so it may have to do with the way I am instantiating the unmarshaller, but I can't seem to find the problem anywhere.

The error/exception I keep getting is:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'calculateBorrowingDataResponse'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:47)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:236)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:119)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:102)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:299)
    ... 2 more
```

Here are the source files that are causing the error.

Java Code:

```
// We need a Document
InputStream is = UnmarshalTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("calculateBorrowingDataResponse.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Node node = db.parse(is);

// Creating an unmarshaller
Unmarshaller u = JAXBContext.newInstance(CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class).createUnmarshaller();

// Setting the Validation
Schema schema;
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse.xsd"));
u.setSchema(schema);
u.unmarshal(node, CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class);
```

CalculateBorrowingDataResponse.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
    version="1.1"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse" 
    xmlns:lssSt="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse"
    xmlns:cbdRes="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


    <!-- CalculateBorrowingData -->
    <xsd:complexType name="CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="loanAgmt" type="cbdRes:LoanAgreementType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>


    <xsd:complexType name="LoanAgreementType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="borrowingBasedPmtAmt" type="lssSt:borrowingBasedPmtAmt" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="maxPmtAmt" type="lssSt:maxPmtAmt" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="borrowingCapacityMin" type="lssSt:borrowingCapacityMin" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="borrowingCapacityMax" type="lssSt:borrowingCapacityMax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="propertyValueMinAmt" type="lssSt:propertyValueMinAmt" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="propertyValueMaxAmt" type="lssSt:propertyValueMaxAmt" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="calculateBorrowingDataResponse" type="cbdRes:CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType"/>


    <xsd:simpleType name="borrowingBasedPmtAmt">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="maxPmtAmt">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="borrowingCapacityMin">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="borrowingCapacityMax">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="propertyValueMinAmt">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="propertyValueMaxAmt">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

calculateBorrowingDataResponse.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<calculateBorrowingDataResponse
    xmlns="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/V1.1">
    <loanAgmt>
        <borrowingBasedPmtAmt>1231231</borrowingBasedPmtAmt>
        <maxPmtAmt>987654321</maxPmtAmt>
        <borrowingCapacityMax>99999</borrowingCapacityMax>
    </loanAgmt>
</calculateBorrowingDataResponse>
```

I tried both with and without the last element definition in the XSD (ie: xsd:element name="calculateBorrowingDataResponse" ... ) but neither work.

I'm running out of ideas of different things to try. Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you create your JAXB classes by hand or with XJC? Also, what is *SimpleType.xsd* that you're referencing? Without these information it's hard run a quick test.

Comment: Yes - I generated the classes with XJC.  I actually tried both with XJC and with the eclipse plugin (using jaxb-2.1.9-osgi from maven central as my jaxb implementation in my pom).  I get the same error both ways.  

I have edited my question above and replaced the original XSD schema with a new version that includes the relevant types from SimpleType.xsd so that there is only one schema file and no longer any dependence on SimpleType.xsd.  Just for clarity, however, I left the original name space identifier.

Comment: I've also edited my post to add the definition for my calculateBorrowingDataResponse.xml sample data.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the *fourth* hour that I'm trying to find the source of the problem. After much struggle, now, I'm confident that you're missing a *single line of code* to be able to rise to glorious heights!

The problem is that `DocumentBuilderFactory` created via `DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()` by default *isn't namespace aware*—yeah.

You can overcome this in two ways:

1. make your `DocumentBuilderFactory` namespace aware:

   [`DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware%28boolean%29)
2. or use a `StreamSource` while unmarshalling and drop the `DocumentBuilder` and his little friends altogether:

   [`Unmarshaller.unmarshal(StreamSource, Class<T>);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20java.lang.Class%29)

In case of the second choice you're to do it like this.

```
InputStream xsdStream = ...
InputStream xmlStream = ...

SchemaFactory f = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema s = schemaFactory.newSchema(xsdStream);

JAXBContext c = JAXBContext.newInstance(CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class);
Unmarshaller u = c.createUnmarshaller();
u.setSchema(schema);
CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType b = 
  u.unmarshal(new StreamSource(xmlStream), CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class);
```

By the way, on this *schema-awareness-ness-document-builderness-awesomeness* there is a *lot* info in the top section of the [`Unmarshaller` class' documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html), you should definitely check that out!

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for having spent so much time on this.  I spent 8+ hours on this, but then again it was my problem to solve in the first place.  If I could upvote you more, I would. :)  I think I came to the same conclusion around the same time; I had not realized that the DocumentBuilderFactory was not namespace aware by default, and furthermore, I had no idea that it would make such a difference.  I was clued in when I found a class called DOMUtils (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/ComparetwoDOMNodes.htm) that clued me in.

Comment: @EricB. _I had not realized that the DocumentBuilderFactory was not namespace aware by default, and furthermore, I had no idea that it would make such a difference._ Me neither, however it was a good lesson for us, so that we check the docs more thoroughly in the future. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  Unfortunately, my JaxB problems  continue; similar vein, but different problem.  This time, my schema generation from my JAXB generated classes is incomplete.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I created a new thread as it is a different problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809406/jaxbcontext-generating-incomplete-schemas

Comment: Respect for spending 4 hours of your time investigating this issue!
Upvote from me purely for that...