# jaxbcontext generating incomplete schemas?

Tags: xml, jaxb, schema

I've run into a strange problem with JAXB.  I've used xjc to generate my java classes from my XSD and all looks good.  If I use schemagen, it produces a proper schema that matches my original xsd.  However, if I use JAXBContext.generateSchema(), then the generated schema is incomplete.

I'm using Oracle Java 1.6.0_29 and jaxb-2.2.4-1.jar as the implementation.  I'm enclosing the java code (which generates the schema), and the xsd below as well as the output of the jaxb call.

CalculateBorrowingDataResponse.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
    version="1.1"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse" 
    xmlns:lssSt="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse"
    xmlns:cbdRes="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


    <!-- CalculateBorrowingData -->
    <xsd:complexType name="CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="loanAgmt" type="cbdRes:LoanAgreementType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>


    <xsd:complexType name="LoanAgreementType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="borrowingBasedPmtAmt" type="lssSt:borrowingBasedPmtAmt" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="maxPmtAmt" type="lssSt:maxPmtAmt" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="borrowingCapacityMin" type="lssSt:borrowingCapacityMin" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="borrowingCapacityMax" type="lssSt:borrowingCapacityMax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="propertyValueMinAmt" type="lssSt:propertyValueMinAmt" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="propertyValueMaxAmt" type="lssSt:propertyValueMaxAmt" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="calculateBorrowingDataResponse" type="cbdRes:CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType"/>


    <xsd:simpleType name="borrowingBasedPmtAmt">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="maxPmtAmt">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="borrowingCapacityMin">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="borrowingCapacityMax">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="propertyValueMinAmt">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="propertyValueMaxAmt">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal" >
        <xsd:totalDigits value="19" />
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Java code:

```
    // Creating the XML tree
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class );
    Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

    // generate the schemas
    final List<ByteArrayOutputStream> schemaStreams = new ArrayList<ByteArrayOutputStream>();
    jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver(){
        @Override
        public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            schemaStreams.add(out);
            StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(out);
            streamResult.setSystemId("");
            return streamResult;
        }});

    // convert to a list of string
    List<String> schemas = new ArrayList<String>();
    for( ByteArrayOutputStream os : schemaStreams )
    {
        schemas.add(os.toString());
        System.out.println( os.toString());
    }
```

Output of jaxbContext.generateSchema():

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse" xmlns:tns="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="loanAgmt" type="tns:LoanAgreementType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="LoanAgreementType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="borrowingBasedPmtAmt" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="maxPmtAmt" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="borrowingCapacityMin" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="borrowingCapacityMax" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="propertyValueMinAmt" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="propertyValueMaxAmt" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

As you can see, the output schema matches very closely, save and except that it is missing the element definition of calculateBorrowingDataResponse!  If I use schemagen, however, the 
calculateBorrowingDataResponse element is generated.

Am I missing something in my SchemaOutputResolver setup or doing something incorrect/incomplete?  Or is this a bug in the Jaxb RI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class);
```

to

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class.getPackage().getName());
```

JAXB needs the information defined in the `package-info.java` file (generated by `xjc` from your XSD) inside the above class' package.

It doesn't creates the XSD element in question, because `CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType` doesn't have an `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

Why didn't `xjc` create one from the beginning? See [the most authoritative explanation on the *Internets* regarding this matter](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/03/why_does_jaxb_p.html).

And why does your code generates the aforementioned element if you supply a package name to `JAXBContext.newInstance(...)` even though `CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType` still missing the `@XmlRootAnnotation`? <strike>*I haven't got the faintest idea!*</strike> [*Now I have!*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8810207/433835)

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the fast response.  Even though I read through the docs multiple times, I still expected that JAXB would have scanned the containing package for the referenced ObjectFactory() and package-info files.  Changing it to the package name worked as advertised.

Comment: +1 - I have also added an answer explaining that is the `ObjectFactory` class that is responsible for causing that element to be generated in the XML schema.  Your approach is one way to do this, the other is to include the `ObjectFactory` in the classes used to bootstrap the JAXBContext:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8810207/383861

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I prefer not to include `ObjectFactory` classes in `JAXBContext.newInstance(...)`, because if I have multiple XJC generated packages then there is namespace clash between them. +1 for the _find_ and explanation!

Answer (score 5):

The following from the generated `ObjectFactory` class is what causes that element to be generated:

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse", name = "calculateBorrowingDataResponse")
public JAXBElement<CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType> createCalculateBorrowingDataResponse(CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType value) {
    return new JAXBElement<CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType>(_CalculateBorrowingDataResponse_QNAME, CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class, null, value);
}
```

In order to have the `ObjectFactory` class processed by the JAXBContext you either need to included in array of classes passed to create the JAXBContext:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class, ObjectFactory.class);
```

Or to create the JAXBContext on the package name of the generated classes:

```
String contextPath = CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class.getPackage().getName();
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath);
```

---

**Full Example**

```
package forum8809406;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.SchemaOutputResolver;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("forum8809406");
        jc.generateSchema(new SOR());
    }

    private static class SOR extends SchemaOutputResolver {

        @Override
        public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
            result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

I get the following generated XML schema, that contains the `calculateBorrowingDataResponse` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema 
    version="1.0" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.domain.com/ClientServices/LendingSimulation/CalculateBorrowingDataResponse" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="loanAgmt" type="tns:LoanAgreementType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="LoanAgreementType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="borrowingBasedPmtAmt" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="maxPmtAmt" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="borrowingCapacityMin" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="borrowingCapacityMax" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="propertyValueMinAmt" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="propertyValueMaxAmt" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="calculateBorrowingDataResponse" type="tns:CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that in roundrip 'schema1->XJC->schema2' schema1 and schema 2 should be identical? Do you have Java class generated for 'calculateBorrowingDataResponse' element by XJC? I don't think so - how would you expect it to be in generated schema then?

Comment: _Do you have Java class generated for 'calculateBorrowingDataResponse' element by XJC?_ He actually does have the `CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class` as he first compiles `CalculateBorrowingDataResponse.xsd` with `xjc`. I can't see the point in generating classes from a schema, then generating a schema from the generated classes, but who am I to judge?

Comment: Well, Type is different from Element. He does have class for Type but not for Element from schema.

Comment: @maximdim. No - you are correct.  I do not have a java class for the generated element.  However, if schemagen can produce a proper xsd from the CalculateBorrowingDataResponseType.class file, I naturally assumed that jaxb.generateSchema() would be able to as well.

Comment: @Kohanyi. The point in generating classes from a schema and then generating the schemas at runtime is to avoid requiring the schemas (and the file IO operations) at runtime.  Like this the Java classes are created at compile time, and at runtime, the schema files are no longer required.  Given that there is a certain cost in generating the schemas on the fly, I plan on caching them so that there is only a performance hit once (at the cost of memory).  Granted, one can do the same with the xsd files as well, but that would require having the xsds as part of the classpath.

Comment: @maximdim Yeah that's true, but if you check my answer then you can see that if I create a `JAXBContext` by using a package name JAXB can figure out somehow to create an element. Still, you're right about types aren't elements.